# Group by dynamically generated column with pattern in `dplyr`

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

I am trying to group by a column that is dynamically generated inside previous steps in my function. The column will have a pattern (suffix). I could use `dplyr::contains()`, but it is not the most accurate way, since I only have one column and could potentially create nasty bugs if other columns with suffix appear in the future.

```
fun <- function(df, target){
  # previous steps generate a dynamic columns
  # dynamic columns have suffixes
  # let's assume I only care about Length
  df %>% 
    group_by("{target}.Length")
  # do more stuff
}
```

I am using `dplyr == 1.0.8` and thought that I this type of thing was supported. I am probably missing something really simple, and `"Petal"` does not get pasted properly and interpreted as a proper column name. I tried several combinations of `{}` and `{{}}` and it is not working as I would expect. For example:

```
> fun(iris, "Petal") %>% head()
# A tibble: 6 × 6
# Groups:   "{target}.Length" [1]
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species `"{target}.Length"`
         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <chr>              
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa  {target}.Length    
2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa  {target}.Length    
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa  {target}.Length    
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa  {target}.Length    
5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa  {target}.Length    
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa  {target}.Length
```

I am using the same type of notation for `mutate()` successfully, but it doesn't for `group_by()`.

Comment: [This post](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/02/glue-strings-and-tidy-eval/) has several examples but not exaclty the one I'm looking for

Comment: Try `group_by(!! sym(paste0(target, "Length")))`

Comment: @TimTeaFan This seems to work happy to upvote if you post as an answer with some blurb explaining why

Comment: I posted my answer with some explanation below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `!! sym(...)` on a string to evaluate it early as object (name).

We can also use the `.data` pronoun, but when using it inside a package you should import it to avoid `R CMD check` notes (see [here](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/rlang/html/dot-data.html)).

```r
library(dplyr)

fun <- function(df, target){
  df %>% 
    group_by(!! sym(paste0(target,".Length")))
}

fun(iris, "Petal") %>% head()

#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#> # Groups:   Petal.Length [4]
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#> 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#> 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa
```

Why does this work?

Lets have a look at it step by step when building our function above:

```r
fun1 <- function(df){
  df %>% 
    group_by("Sepal.Length")
}
```

⬇️ groups by new variable which is named after its value / call

```r
iris %>% 
  fun1()
#> # A tibble: 150 x 6
#> # Groups:   "Sepal.Length" [1]
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species `"Sepal.Length"`
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <chr>           
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa  Sepal.Length    
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa  Sepal.Length    
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa  Sepal.Length    
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa  Sepal.Length    
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa  Sepal.Length    
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa  Sepal.Length    
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa  Sepal.Length    
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa  Sepal.Length    
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa  Sepal.Length    
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa  Sepal.Length    
#> # ... with 140 more rows

fun2 <- function(df){
  df %>% 
    group_by(as.name("Sepal.Length"))
}
```

⬇️ error: group_by needs a vetor as input, but has received a `name` / `symbol`

```r
iris %>% 
  fun2()
#> Error in `add_computed_columns()`:
#> ! Problem adding computed columns in `group_by()`.
#> x Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
#> i `..1 = as.name("Sepal.Length")`.
#> x `..1` must be a vector, not a symbol.
#> Caused by error in `mutate_cols()`:
#> ! Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
#> i `..1 = as.name("Sepal.Length")`.
#> x `..1` must be a vector, not a symbol.



fun3 <- function(df){
  df %>% 
    group_by(eval(as.name("Sepal.Length")))
}
```

⬇️ works, but creates new column which is named after call to `eval`:

```r
iris %>% 
  fun3()
#> # A tibble: 150 x 6
#> # Groups:   eval(as.name("Sepal.Length")) [35]
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species `eval(as.name("Sep~
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>                 <dbl>
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa                  5.1
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa                  4.9
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa                  4.7
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa                  4.6
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa                  5  
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa                  5.4
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa                  4.6
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa                  5  
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa                  4.4
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa                  4.9
#> # ... with 140 more rows


fun4 <- function(df){
  df %>% 
    group_by(!! as.name("Sepal.Length"))
}
```

⬇️ works: `!!` does the same as `eval`, but works only inside `rlang` powered functions and it is evaluated faster than the normal `eval`. For this reason `group_by` correctly gets the name of the column to evaluate.

```r
iris %>% 
  fun4()
#> # A tibble: 150 x 5
#> # Groups:   Sepal.Length [35]
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
#> # ... with 140 more rows

fun5 <- function(df){
  df %>% 
    group_by(!! sym("Sepal.Length"))
}
```

works: `sym` is almost simmilar to base R’s `as.name`, but it's shorter.

```r
iris %>% 
  fun5()

#> # A tibble: 150 x 5
#> # Groups:   Sepal.Length [35]
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
#> # ... with 140 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

While I use this kind of `glue` pattern quite often for assignments inside `mutate` and `summarise` I haven't seen any examples of using it in other `dplyr` verbs. However, one option would be use the `.data` pronoun and `paste0` which is not that elegant but works:

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)

fun <- function(df, target){
  df %>% 
    group_by(.data[[paste0(target, ".Length")]])
}

fun(iris, "Petal") %>% head()
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#> # Groups:   Petal.Length [4]
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#> 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#> 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa
```

Comment: This is interesting, I had totally forgot about the `.data` thing... Is there something "special" about `group_by()` that will take `group_by({{var}})` but not the pattern I was trying ?

Comment: Citing from the the post you referenced: "For this reason, tidy eval functions taking dots (like dplyr::mutate(), dplyr::group_by(), or dplyr::summarise()) now support glue strings as result names.". As I interpret this, `glue` patterns can only be used on the LHS of an assignment.

Comment: That would explain things

Comment: ... not really sure whether using `glue` patterns in `group_by` are that useful but you could e.g. do `df %>% group_by("{target}.foo" := Petal.Length)` but that is of course not what you are looking for.